# asp.net web applications and data plans

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, mobile

I have a asp.net 4.0 web application that uses linqtosql to insert/update/delete data from a sql server 2005 database.
The application is elastic and therefore fits on any device... phone, ipad or desktop.
On phones and ipads users will normally have a data plan.
What I want to know is when a user is connected to my application,  but not inserting/updating/deleting data, is it affecting data usage?
Also is there data usage if a user is just looking at pages or does data usage only occur when data is being inserted/updated/deleted?

Thanks

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question. It is not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell if you're trolling or not...

But if you aren't, then you don't understand how web applications work. If it appears in the browser window then it means the user agent (the browser in the device) downloaded it from the web server, that download eats into the device's data allowance. The fact that data was possibly moved around on the server side is irrelevant.

When a web user agent (i.e. a browser) submit data back to the server (usually via a POST request) then that too will eat into the data allowance, but HTML forms typically consume less than a kilobyte of data when being sent from the client (unless you're uploading binary files or large textareas). Data allowances are usually bi-directional, so you might have 1GB to use for both upstream and downstream - the few kilobytes you use uploading a form's data are massively outweighed by the fact that most webpages thesedays weigh a few hundred kilobytes, if not more.

Of course, the right answer in this case is "profile!" - run your application yourself and see how much data you go through when performing common tasks, record your findings, and act accordingly.

Comment: I was afraid that because the device was using the browser, it would cost data. Is there a tool that can convert an asp.net application to run on the ipad, yet still access the data on my server?... or is that basically the same thing I am doing now. Fortunately on all my devices I have unlimited data, but that is difficult to get now.

Comment: There is no automated process, you'd have to rewrite the presentation layer for iOS (but you can use C# if you use MonoTouch) and use a web-services connection or access the SQL Server directly but you'd be responsible for caching your own data. Yes, this would reduce data transfer, but not by much (since browsers cache images and other things anyway). What are you doing that's so data intensive anyway?

Comment: I have built an application for hair stylists who are independent contractors.  This application does it all... www.styliststudioinc.com.  If you go to the site, keep in mind it is in debug mode.

Comment: I ran a few pages of your application's public-facing website through Chrome's profiler, your site isn't heavy at all. I'd say this really isn't anything worth worrying about right now.

Comment: Thank you for running it, I am trying to keep load times down. However, in the stylist pages are heavy because of data access, creating services, formulas, retail, inventory etc. Is there a way to make the program run off-line until there is a button click or page request or does it not matter once it's loaded.

Comment: In short, no; but I think you need to understand how the web works so you can answer that question yourself. Play around with Chrome or Safari's Inspector tools to see what's going on.